# How can I solve java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) error?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets

I am trying to make a project on Servlets using JDBC. But there are some persistent errors in the error log like `java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)`, `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)`, `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)`, `java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)` etc. How can I solve such errors from happening?
I am using Apache Tomcat v7.0, mySQL Community Server v5.7 and Eclipse IDE.

This my error log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.driver.JDBC
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Register.register(Register.java:10)
    at RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:34)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the JDBC file code(Register.java):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Register {
    public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    public static final Pattern VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX = Pattern.compile("[7-9][0-9]\\d{9}"); // ,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    public static int register(String name,String user,String pass,String cpass,String email, String phone,String city,String state) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        int status=0;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.driver.JDBC");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:localhost:8080/Diary.db");
            System.out.println("Database connected successfully!!");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Trial(name, user, pass, email, phone, city, state, authorized) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            if(pass!=null && cpass!=null && phone!=null && name!=null && user!=null && city!=null && state!=null){
                Matcher matcher1 = VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX .matcher(email);
                Matcher matcher2 = VALID_PHONE_NUMBER_REGEX .matcher(phone);
                if((pass==cpass) && (matcher1.find()) && (matcher2.find())){
                    ps.setString(1,name);
                    ps.setString(2,user);
                    ps.setString(3,pass);
                    ps.setString(4,email);
                    ps.setString(5,phone);
                    ps.setString(6,city);
                    ps.setString(7,state);
                    ps.setString(8,"yes");

                    status=ps.executeUpdate();
                }
                else{
                    status = 0;
                }
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){e.getMessage();}

        return status;
    }
}
```

This is my servlet (RegisterSevlet.java):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        int status;
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();        
        String name=req.getParameter("name");
        String user=req.getParameter("user");
        String pass=req.getParameter("pass");
        String cpass=req.getParameter("cpass");
        String email=req.getParameter("email"); 
        String phone=req.getParameter("phone");
        String city=req.getParameter("city");
        String state=req.getParameter("state");
        try {
            status = Register.register(name, user, pass, cpass, email, phone, city, state);             
            if(status > 0){
                out.print("<p>You are successfully registered!</p>");
                req.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(req, res);

            }
            else if(status == 0){
                out.println("<p>Enter the information correctly!</p>");
                res.sendRedirect("register.html");
            }

            req.getRequestDispatcher("#").include(req, res);
            out.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you include JDBC driver (jar) into your project?

Comment: yes I did include the JDBC driver in the servlet external library

Comment: share your code too.

Comment: i have shared my code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`Class.forName()`
```

throws `ClassNotFoundException`
 You need to include multicatch statement for that (same catch for `SQLException` and `ClassNotFoundException`)
You can modify your catch statement to this:

```
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Try this. You can use a multicatch statement wherever you need to catch multiple exceptions.

Comment: but they are two different files, one is a JDBC file: Register.java and another is a servlet: RegisterServlet.java

Comment: Use this multicatch only where you are using `Class.forName()` i.e. in JDBC file `Register.java` @Code_Ninja

Comment: Even after using the multicatch statement, I get this error [Error](https://snag.gy/vQbs0F.jpg)

Comment: Alright this is a different error altogether. It's a `FileNotFoundException`.  It's unable to find the file `/Diary/%23` in your `RegisterServlet.java`. Maybe the file name doesn't contain `%` in it's name as you may have wrongly written in your code (line 44 according to the error report). Check that out. Also. if you are using an IDE (Eclipse in this case), then you don't need to write it as `/Diary/23` . Just write the file name and it'll search for the file automatically. If you actually have named the file as %23 then try changing it's name and keep it in the same folder as your project.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help. Sorry for the downvote, I am underrated to vote now.

Answer (score -1):

This exception is thrown whenever a class existed at compile time but not at run time.
Please check that at runtime ur classpath is correct and you are pointing to the library in question  (in ur case the mysql connector jar).